# Button text bolder than link text despite CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a link designed as button and and a real button.
For some reason the text of both have a different font-weight, despite of the same font-weight and font-size. How can I fix this?

[image]

The designed pseudo button:

```
.btn {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
outline: 0;
border: 0;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ED7004;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 100;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
line-height: normal;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
}
```

The real button:

```
input[type="button"] {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
outline: 0;
border: 0;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ED7004;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 100;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
line-height: normal;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
}
```

Thanx!

Comment: what font are you using and what are the fallbacks? are you using webkit fonts?

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: In my case, I had to set `font-family: inherit;` for the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure both use the exact same font?
With Arial both look pretty much the same to me:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Input Button">
<div class="btn">Button Class</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
  font-family: Arial;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ED7004;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
}

input[type="button"] {
  font-family: Arial;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ED7004;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.3);
}
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/zeitwidrig/pen/jEJJQN)

Though there are still visible differences between browsers. If you want a light font for the button (and the same look in all browsers) it may be better to use an appropriate (web) font instead of font-weight: 100

Comment: That is probably it. For some reason buttons don't seem to be rendered with the font defined in 'body {}'

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll call this one "Cascading Style Shit".

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem,  and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```css
font-rendering: geometricPrecision;
```